# HTTPS on Raspberry Pie is too slow. What can I do about it? Which cipher should I choose?

Tags: java, ssl, youtube-api, raspberry-pi, apache-httpclient-4.x

## The Problem

Uploading videos from my raspberry pie to YouTube using the YouTube Data Api v3 is too slow. The max rate I get is 120 KB/s. I want to be able to archieve rates up to 1MB/s.

## Why I believe SSL is the problem

To Upload Videos to YouTube I used to run a small java program which I could run on a Raspberry Pie over night to save power. It is connected to the YouTube Data API v2. I have three internet connections and the fastest is a LTE mobile connection. With that one **my old app can upload with 1 Megabyte/second** (and it does so very reliable up until the moment my 30GB included data is used up, which is why I use it in urgent cases only).

Now I have created a successor for my app, which uses the API v3. In contrast to the v2 API uploads now also use HTTPS connections. However now I cannot upload any faster than 120 KB/s.

Many hours of frustrated debugging later, I believe that the problem is due to the CPU load created by SSL. To verify this I started an enterprise grade *caugh* HTTPS Sever on my computer (connected to the raspberry pie via ethernet):

```bash
# create a self signed certificate (answer all the question it asks with default)
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 100 -nodes
# Run the server on port 5454:
openssl s_server -accept 5454 -key key.pem -cert cert.pem > /dev/null
```

I assembled a small Java program which uses Apache HttpClient 4.3 (just like my app does) and performed a video "upload":

```java
    final ProgressReportingHttpEntity entity = new ProgressReportingHttpEntity(new FileEntity(SOME_VIDEO_FILE, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpClientBuilder
        .create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    new SSLContextBuilder()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .build(),
                    new AllowAllHostnameVerifier()
            )
        )
        .build().execute(request);
```

My laptop can transmit to itself 60MB/s (12% CPU go to Java (one core of my i7), 8% go to OpenSSL) using this setup.

The raspberry pie can still transmit 1MB/s (which would be fast enough). However as far as I understand [this page here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.googleapis.com&s=74.125.239.52), the googleapis-Server will prefer the cipher `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. Thus I restarted my local server like this:

```bash
openssl s_server -accept 5454 -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 > /dev/null
```

And BINGO! I will not get any better transmission rates than 120KB/s.

I tried around with different ciphers, setting the supported ciphers explicitly in the apache HTTP client and e.g. the cipher `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` did very well, going up to 1,3MB/s.

## The question

What can I do about it? Which cipher would provide a decent balance between performance and security? After comparing supported cipher charts and blindly guessing I thought that `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` might be a good choice and would be supported by google. But actually it looks like it is not (setting this cipher in apache http client enables communication with my test server, but breaks with google).

Or is there anything else I could do to speed up SSL throughput? E.g. is there an ARM optimized SSL library that I can somehow inject into the JRE (in case the Java 8 ARM JRE does not already contain such a thing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your must have misread something at some point. When your tried the cipher `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` you probably actually wanted to try `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` (they surely look similar).

Initialize your http client like this:

```java
return HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .disableAutomaticRetries()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    new SSLContextBuilder().build(),
                    null,
                    new String[] { "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" },
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
            )
        )
        .build();
```

According to my tests this will be fast enough to do your uploads with 1MB/s on your raspberry pie.

Unfortunately I am no security expert and I can't tell you what this choice means for your security. Also I don't know how fragile it makes your app if you support only a single cipher.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Hurray! And concerning your considerations, maybe someone else can say something about this choice.

Comment: Dude...did you just answer your own question in second person and then respond to yourself?

Comment: `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` use the same symmetric cipher. You should *not* see a difference in speed once key agreement is complete (key agreement is the Diffie-Hellman portion executed during the handshake).

Comment: @jww: The important thing is that the DHE cipher is rejected by google and the ECDHE is not. When I asked my question I accidentially used DHE and was surprised to see that it does not work at all.

Comment: @JNYRanger: Yes. I think that makes reading the question/answer flow here easier to follow. Also it is more fun.

Comment: @yankee - Oh, you're right. I did not know they disabled that. `openssl s_client -connect www.googleapis.com:443 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` failed with a handshake alert due to no shared ciphers.

Comment: @yankee - an FYI... If you use one of the `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_*`, then you need to (1) disable compression or (2) use TLS and enable SNI. Otherwise, it will fail too. Its a Google server configuration quirk. See [ECDHE-ECDSA Support](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/To-6X1LtkpY/VZxnRNVOGycJ) on the OpenSSL users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way around this problem is to avoid the SSL connection altogether and instead upload the videos via SMTP using YouTube's "Upload Via EMAIL" option...

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57407?hl=en

Once you get your your unique email address for uploading videos from your YouTube settings page, there are many ways to actually send the email from your RaspberryPi, and you could use straight SMTP without encryption for maximum performance.

While you might be concerned that SMTP is too inefficient for uploading video thanks to base64 encoding, it seems as though YouTube wisely supports 8-bit encoding via [RFC 3030](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030). Here is a quick TELNET test showing their supported capabilities...

```
220 gmr-mx.google.com ESMTP hq8si1005325qcb.2 - gsmtp
EHLO josh.com
250-gmr-mx.google.com at your service, [108.29.37.132]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Comment: I need to be able to resume interrupted uploads which cannot be done using SMTP. Additionally attached data is base64 encoded in SMTP because SMTP is a 7bit ASCII protocol. This adds a 33.33% overhead to the data which is very substantial.

Comment: If an SMTP transaction is interrupted, you can retry it

Comment: > This adds a 33.33% overhead to the data which is very substantial: it does not have to be. The server supports 8BITMIME

Comment: > I need to be able to resume interrupted uploads: I think this can be done given the server supports CHUNKING

Comment: @oleg: Good point about the 8BITMIME. However, as far as I understand CHUNKING it is not possible to resume an interrupted session. Additionally my tool also sets description, tags, thumbnail playlist etc. If I'd upload using SMTP I somehow need to poll existing videos in my account and add metadata later. Furthermore my authentication (my secret email address) is transmitted in clear text which I don't like. Then the YouTube API v3 allows max 64 GB video files. I could not find what the limit for SMTP uploads is.